# How to say: "This advice/guideline was distributed via (newspaper X、Y and news agency Z)"?

Tags: translation, terminology

How to say: "**This advice/guideline was distributed via** (newspaper X、Y and news agency Z)" please?

What I mean with `advice` or `guideline` is a set of principles propagated by a certain research institution or government agency to e.g. prepare your home for the impact of a natural disaster.

---

P.S.: It's not necessary to translate "*(newspaper X、Y and news agency Z)*", nor the words "*newspaper*" or "*news agency*" (I am just trying to clarify the context)  Feel free to translate it as e.g. **XYZ**.

Please note that the purpose of this sentence is to be spoken out loud. And the summation of all the newspapers and news agency might take a long while to pronounce. Therefor, it is my intuition that the summation of these news channels would best occur at the utmost end of the sentence, while all other parts of the sentence have already been placed beforehand? I think it will be easier for the listener to understand.

Comment: e。g。该指示（指导准则）是XY发送的

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Guideline for  natural disasters' could be translated to 自然灾害的防護準則.

via: 通過

distributed: 傳播

So, as a whole: 自然灾害的防護準則 通過 xyz 來 傳播 。

Answer (score 0):

[此=this]

[項 = item of] (classifier for 指引)

[指引= guideline]

[經由 = via]

[發佈 = distribute]

> "此項指引經由 衛生部 發佈"
>
> "此項指引經由 運輸署 發佈"